# Callbacks and Async Execution in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a function that generates a bunch of data into a DB for testing, then at the end sends a textual response to the browser. I'm new to node and see the response and text is printing before any of the execution has even completed.

I've tried a bunch of different ways to see sequential execution, below is one of the crazy poor ways, but still not working. What can I do to ensure the for-loop data completes, c.end() executes and then DONE is called?
//Generate the new data to persist into the database
    function data_generation(call_back) {

```
  //Force generate random entries into the test DB (eventually change to monitor individual key requests)
  for (var i = 0; i < NUM_ENTRIES; i++) {
    c.query("INSERT INTO individual_key_log \
              (reference_key, access_count, last_updated, last_ip) \
                VALUES ('Johnson" + Math.random()*100 + "', " + (Math.random()*100) +", '"+Date.now()+"', '"+req.connection.remoteAddress+"'\
              );",
            function(err, rows) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      else {
        console.log("Counter: " + counter);
        counter++;
      }
    });
    call_back();
  }
};

function completion_func() {
  console.log("DONE");
  res.send("done");
};


data_generation(completion_func);
```

Comment: These should help: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+loop+async+wait

Comment: Do you understand how an async operation works in node?  That's the core of your mistake.  There are hundreds of other answers here that explain, even answers that address async operations inside a loop.

Comment: I'm trying to understand, but still having difficulty after reading.